# Error when call require_once using PhpImageWorkshop

Tags: php

I has installed from this link http://phpimageworkshop.com/installation.html

But when I run wampserver in localhost is error

```
demo/ImageWorkshop.php
    /index.php
    /test.jpg
```

in index.php i using code:

```
<?php
require_once('C:\\wamp\www\demo\ImageWorkshop.php');

$norwayLayer = new ImageWorkshop(array(
    "imageFromPath" => "norway.jpg",
));
?>
```

Error: `Fatal error: Class 'ImageWorkshop' not found in C:\wamp\www\demo\index.php on line xx`

Comment: really file ImageWorkshop.php exist in demo folder ? or try just require_once('ImageWorkshop.php');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open ImageWorkshop.php file, and then remove the namespace declaration line 3:

```
namespace PHPImageWorkshop;
```

And the namespace inclusion line 5:

```
use PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshopException;
```

Then, with your text editor, replace all the founded occurences "`static::`" by "`self::`".
Final:

```
require_once('ImageWorkshopException.php');
```

I has config successfull, good luck !!!